# How to check if two field match in SPLUNK

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

number1= AnyNumber from 1 to 100
number2= AnyNumber from 1 to 100,
This is how my data looks in Splunk

```
{[-]
   field1: number1,
   fiedl2: number2,
   ...
}
```

I want to check if these two fields match or doesn't,
my Splunk Query

```
| search filed1 != field2
| stats count by field1,field2
```

Comment: How is that query not giving you the expected results?  Do you want to know if the numbers match, don't match, or either?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the single quotes around the field2. I was able to get the data
for the list of fields that are not matching!
`| where field1 != 'field2' | stats count by field1, field2`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for comparing fields in the same event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`where`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/where) with `match`:

```
<spl>
| where !match(field1,field2)
| stats count by field1 field 2
```

Comment: This did the job
`.  | where field1 != 'field2'
     | stats count by field1, field2
`